# Distribute a weekly quota over weekdays in MySQL

Tags: mysql, math, equation

One of my customers is selling fishing licenses. They have a weekly quota for each of their fishing zones. This quota must be equally divided between the weekdays which are open (some might be closed). Closed days will be represented by a comma separated list containing day numbers from 1-7. E.g. weekly quota for a specific week with no closed days is 14 licenses. This means that there are 2 licenses available for each day of the week.

I need a select that gives the quota for any given date based on a table containing weekly quotas. I've written this query that gives the desired result, but I'm sure it can be written as a much shorter equation without using the CASE statement. However my math skills aren't sufficient for such a solution :p

For day 1, it simply divides the quota by 7.
For day 2, it subtracts the quota for day 1 first, then divides the rest for the remaining 6 days of the week.
... and so on.

If a day are closed, every divisor in the query must be reduced by 1...and so on.

Kvote = Quota

```
            (CASE WEEKDAY(calendar.dy)+1
                WHEN 1 THEN CEIL(Kvote/7)
                WHEN 2 THEN CEIL((Kvote-CEIL(Kvote/7))/6)
                WHEN 3 THEN CEIL((Kvote-CEIL(Kvote/7)-CEIL((Kvote-CEIL(Kvote/7))/6))/5)
                WHEN 4 THEN CEIL((Kvote-CEIL(Kvote/7)-CEIL((Kvote-CEIL(Kvote/7))/6)-CEIL((Kvote-CEIL(Kvote/7)-CEIL((Kvote-CEIL(Kvote/7))/6))/5))/4)
                WHEN 5 ...
                WHEN 6 ...
                WHEN 7 ...
           END) AS DayQuota
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f9ab8/3)

Comment: I dont see how this consider how many licenses were sold monday? and if Sunday are close why you divide by 7?

Comment: You are right. I started writing the question yesterday and finished it today. Meanwhile I did some work that changed the preconditions. I've updated the question now. Sorry.

Comment: Where is the information on which days are open, and which are closed? If it exists, you are not using it in your query.

Comment: Oh, right. Closed days will be represented by a comma-separated list from 1-7. Will update my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression gives the same results as the `CASE WHEN` expression in your question:

```
FLOOR(Kvote/7) + (WEEKDAY(calendar.dy) < Kvote % 7)
```

See comparison in [updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f9ab8/5)

Comment: I love it. Thank you very much! :-)